# How to merge proxy list in imacros

Tags: list, replace, proxy, imacros

I want to merge proxy list into imacros code , without doing manually .

**Here is imacros code**

```
VERSION BUILD=7601105 RECORDER=FX
PROXY ADDRESS=109.175.8.38:8080
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://example.com
WAIT SECONDS= 8
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
PROXY ADDRESS=113.36.36:80
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://example.com
WAIT SECONDS= 8
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
PROXY ADDRESS=111.45.57:80
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://example.com
WAIT SECONDS= 8
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
```

**And here is my proxy list**

```
109.175.8.38:8080
113.36.36:80
111.45.57:80
```

Actually I Have very long list so it would bit hard to replace manually

Comment: Use this code http://wiki.imacros.net/!DATASOURCE

Comment: can please give me a example for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DATASOURCE command that macroscripts alluded to along with Javascript to pull in the values from your file.

You save a DATASOURCE file (csv, txt) in a directory and then point iMacros to that directory by going to the Manage Pane in the sidebar -> Settings -> Paths.  Now you can reference the DATASOURCE in scripts or macros.

[image: Picture]

Here is a small example that will take you to different websites that are stored in a csv file.

```
    var macro, i, retCode;
    // Initialize variables
    i = 0;
    retCode = 0;
    macro = "";
    // loop until error
    do
    {
            i++;
            macro = "CODE:"
            macro += "SET !DATASOURCE sites.csv\n";
            // # of columns in the datasource
            macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1\n";
            // datasource line to pull data
            macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE " + i + "\n";
            // reference to datasource value
            macro += "URL GOTO={{!COL1}}\n";
            // run the macro
            retCode = iimPlay(macro);
    // stop when error is encountered
    } while (retCode === 1);
```

This script iterates through all the rows in the sites.csv.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a little late, but for anybody else with a similar issue:

You could create an iMacro generator in something like Python or PHP that would take a base script and proxy list as an input, then it would output the base script with rotating proxies in the script where specified.

Comment: please explain using an example or snippet rather than putting descriptions so the community can get help out of your answer !